# EXT-JS 4.1: adding custom menu to grid column header without the default menu

Tags: extjs, grid, extjs4.1

i want to add custom menu items to grid column header - which i can do, but apparently it's available only if the custom menu is available.  but if i don't want my columns to be sortable or hideable, the custom menu isn't displayed.
the way in which i create my custom menu is as follows:

```
    var menu = Ext.getCmp('pairsGrid').headerCt.getMenu();
    var customEls = menu.add([{
        xtype: 'menu',
        floating: false,
        items:[
            {
                text: 'Management',
                iconCls: 'edit',
                menu: {
                    xtype: "menu",
                    items: [
                        {
                            text: 'Start'
                        },{
                            text: 'Stop'
                        }
                    ]
                }                   
            }
        ]
    }]);
```

if in my columns config i have `sortable: false` and `hideable: false` my custom menu won't be displayed; otherwise, it's there.
is there any other way to create the menu, or somehow have it visible without the default menu?
cheers,
eRez

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force menu to be visible by overriding `beforeRender` method on column:

```
{
    text     : 'xxx',
    sortable : false,
    hideable : false,
    dataIndex: 'xxx',
    beforeRender: function() {
        Ext.grid.column.Column.prototype.beforeRender.call(this);
        this.menuDisabled = false;
    }
},
```

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/sg9w7/1/

Comment: thanks for you replay.  however, when i tried to add custom menu items in your example, the menu was enlarged to fit the items, but they weren't displayed, and the sorting menu items were still there, though disabled.
Ext.onReady(function() {
    var myGrid = Ext.create('KitchenSink.view.grid.ArrayGrid', {
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
    var menu = myGrid.headerCt.getMenu();
    menu.add([{
        xtype: 'menu',
        floating: false,
        items: [           
            {
                text: 'first'
            },
            ...
        ]
    }])
});

Comment: You should add `menuitem` to menu. If you want submenu, then configure `menu` for `menuitem`: `{ xtype: 'menuitem', text: 'submenu', menu: [...] }`. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/sg9w7/5/
If you don't want to see sorting buttons - hide them, or create custom menu and catch trigger click (`headertriggerclick` event): http://jsfiddle.net/sg9w7/6/

Comment: that's more like it.  i'd rather have the sorting items completely gone, but i'll do with having them disabled, and my custom menu items enabled.  thanks!